# Count of rows returned by 2 out of 3 SELECTs combined with UNION

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, union-all

I have a hard time titling this post.

How can we accomplish the following?

```
SELECT 'Body' AS LineType, ItemName, Quantity FROM TableX
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Body' AS LineType, ItemName, Quantity FROM TableY
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Trailer' AS LineType, null As ItemName, <count of the above two SELECTs>
```

The result should look like this:

```
LineType     ItemName     Qty
Body         Nut          19
Body         Bolt         25
Trailer      NULL         2
```

Please help; Thank you SOF community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try a CTE:

```
;WITH FirstQ AS 
(
    SELECT 'Body' AS LineType, ItemName, Quantity FROM TableX
), SecondQ AS 
(
    SELECT 'Body' AS LineType, ItemName, Quantity FROM TableY
)
SELECT * FROM FirstQ
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM SecondQ
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Trailer' AS LineType, null As ItemName, ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FirstQ) +(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SecondQ)) AS Quantity
```

Working sample code:

```
declare @TableX table (ItemName varchar(5), Quantity int)
INSERT @TableX VALUES ('aa',10)
INSERT @TableX VALUES ('bb',20)

declare @TableY table (ItemName varchar(5), Quantity int)
INSERT @TableX VALUES ('cc',30)

;WITH FirstQ AS 
(
    SELECT 'Body' AS LineType, ItemName, Quantity FROM @TableX
), SecondQ AS 
(
    SELECT 'Body' AS LineType, ItemName, Quantity FROM @TableY
)
SELECT * FROM FirstQ
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM SecondQ
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Trailer' AS LineType, null As ItemName, ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FirstQ) +(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SecondQ)) AS Quantity
```

OUTPUT:

```
LineType ItemName Quantity
-------- -------- -----------
Body     aa       10
Body     bb       20
Body     cc       30
Trailer  NULL     3

(4 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: This works. I'll mark this as an answer as soon as SOF allows me. Thank you for the swift response.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @TableX table (ItemName varchar(10),Quantity int)
declare @TableY table (ItemName varchar(10),Quantity int)

insert @tableX VALUES('door',0)
insert @tableX VALUES('window',10)
insert @tableX VALUES('wheel',5)
insert @tableX VALUES('brake',7)
insert @tableX VALUES('handle',3)
insert @tableX VALUES('lamp',207)

insert @tableY VALUES('Ydoor',0)
insert @tableY VALUES('Ywindow',10)
insert @tableY VALUES('Ywheel',5)
insert @tableY VALUES('Ybrake',7)
insert @tableY VALUES('Yhandle',3)
insert @tableY VALUES('Ylamp',207)

SELECT 'Body' as LineType, ItemName, Sum(Quantity) qty, Count(*) [count] FROM
(
SELECT ItemName, Quantity FROM @TableX
UNION
SELECT ItemName, Quantity FROM @TableY
) u

GROUP BY ItemName WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: several errors: need to remove extra `UNION ALL`, need to remove the `as LineType` within the `GROUP BY`. After that, you'll still get: `Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.`

Comment: @KM -- thanks for the proof read.  Too lazy to test.  See revised answer.

Comment: pretty is in the eye of the beholder.  your version does not provide a row with a LineType='Trailer', but instead generates that row as LineType='Body'.  I bet the OP needs that 'Trailer' value for some processing, and having a 'Body' value will not meet their needs.